# iMacros - Exclude original extracted text from being saved in csv

Tags: split, eval, extract, clipboard, imacros

I hope I'm being clear. I'm a total noob. This is my first time asking a question here, too, so I apologise for missing anything that I should've provided.

So what I wanted to achieve is to save / 'split' certain parts of an extracted string in a csv using EVAL. As a simplified model of what I am trying to achieve, here is a modified code from one of the demos in iMacros:

```
URL GOTO=http://www.iopus.com/imacros/demo/v6/extract2/       
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:heading&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT  
SET commandOnly EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(' ')[2];")
ADD !EXTRACT {{commandOnly}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:yyyy-mm-dd<SP>hhh<SP>nnmin}}.csv
```

As you will see, the resultant csv file will have 2 columns populated. I wanted it to result to only one entry in A1 with the word "COMMAND". Is it possible to copy something to the CLIPBOARD without EXTRACTing it? Coz maybe that way, the original extracted text won't reflect in the csv. I would appreciate any solution or workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Running this exact code I get `Overview EXTRACT command,"EXTRACT"` in my .csv, all in the field A1 though. What do you get? Do I understand you correctly, you want the actual literal word "COMMAND" in the file? (Note that it's written "command" on the website.) Or did you mean to only get "EXTRACT" for that specific example? Also, what is your purpose with the CLIPBOARD, why do you set it?

Comment: @PinkiePie Yeah, I noticed the blunder, thanks for pointing that out :D I solved my problem although I'm not sure as to how. I'll share them here in the hope that I may be of help to others, too. So, yeah, I really meant "command". I've fixed the code by replacing [1] with [2]. And yes, the CLIPBOARD part made no sense so I scrapped that, too. Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your initial code is that you used ADD here

`ADD !EXTRACT {{commandOnly}}`

instead of SET. What this did in your case was adding the value in the variable commandOnly to the value !EXTRACT already had instead of overwriting it as SET does.

You can just change the ADD to SET and you're good.

So the full code would be

```
URL GOTO=http://www.iopus.com/imacros/demo/v6/extract2/       
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:heading&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT  
SET commandOnly EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(' ')[2];")
SET !EXTRACT {{commandOnly}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:yyyy-mm-dd<SP>hhh<SP>nnmin}}.csv
```

Further information on ADD http://wiki.imacros.net/ADD and SET http://wiki.imacros.net/set

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I don't know much code-speak. Feel free to correct me on anything, if it helps the community. Thanks!

I solved my problem by using SET !EXTRACT NULL. I'm not very sure how they should be used but it looks like we have to NULL extractions between each EXTRACT commands. Do note that the example above is just a simple reference and that the actual macro I'm working on has a number of extracted strings and hence, positioning of the SET !EXTRACT NULL is key. I also made sure that that my ADD !EXTRACT commands are as  close as possible to the SAVEAS (at the bottom!). Doing these have prevented the originally extracted strings from being populated into the csv --- Especially useful if you're modifying the extracted strings (i.e. EVAL's replace, substr, etc.)

Here's the fixed version of the problematic code above:

```
URL GOTO=http://www.iopus.com/imacros/demo/v6/extract2/       
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:heading&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT  
SET commandOnly EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(' ')[2];")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
ADD !EXTRACT {{commandOnly}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:yyyy-mm-dd<SP>hhh<SP>nnmin}}.csv
```

Comment: You can avoid setting !EXTRACT to NULL if you write a new value to it right afterwards, just use SET :)

Comment: I can' t thank you enough.  Actually, how can I do that in here? Aside from the fact that my upvote does not seem to reflect anything haha :)

Comment: Upvoting/Accepting answers is the way to go here :) Upvoting requires a reputation of 15, though, to make abuse with fake accounts harder.https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: :D That is noted.